# Spring WebFlux Authentication CSRF Rotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, csrf, spring-webflux, csrf-protection

In spring web mvc with spring security when I setup CSRF using minimum config (mostly defaults) like follows:

```
 protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .formLogin().and()
        .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository);
}
```

When I authenticate (with a `POST /login` I notice some desirable behaviour in that the existing CSRF cookie is rotated to a new value "automatically" (as in I didn't write code to do this or explicitly configure it).

Switching to Webflux seems to change this behaviour. The cookie value appears to remain the same after authentication. Is there a way to restore this behaviour in Webflux?

Version of spring boot is `2.1.1.RELEASE` running on Java 10.